# php mail function & smtp approach not sending email from yahoo.com and some other domains

Tags: email, phpmailer

I am trying to send email from PHP using mail function to gmail ID, but email is not being delivered to the recipient if sender defined in header is yahoo ID, but if sender is hotmail then email comes fine. IF it goes sometime then it gets delivered at spam and the message on top of the message is 'This message may not have been sent by: xxx@xxx.com'

I have also tried phpmailer with smtp and ssl is also enabled on server, but no luck. Server is linux based hosted on godaddy

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't send mail from a yahoo address unless you send it through a yahoo server - documented [here](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail/SLN24016.html). It will be bounced with a DMARC failure.